# Which technology/programming is used for drag and drop web programming?

Tags: php, asp.net

I'd like to work on drag and drop web programming. I want the data to be moved from one panel to another panel by the drag and drop feature as we experience in Google Plus. I might have panels/frames in a page like To-be-done section, Done section etc. When I'm done with a particular item, I'd drag the item from the To-be-done section to the Done section. I've a raw idea at present. Please share your thoughts on which resources (IDE/Programming/Technology) to be useful to begin my project.

Comment: All you need is some wonderful Javascript.

Comment: Anything done within your browser eg moving stuff or dynamic resizing, loading and saving content without refreshing and such is done with javascript, the javascript library `jquery` offers such things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for jQuery UI. It has a draggable,dropable and sortable feature

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Using it is very simple,

1) Include the reference to the jQuery and jQuery ui library in your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Attach the draggable function to the element

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#myDivId" ).draggable();  //
    });
  </script>
```

EDIT : About the size of jQuery UI. It is not 150K. the minified version of jQuery UI is 50KB size. If you are not using jQuery already( really ?) then you need to download that too, Thats another 32.KB. I would like to refer those from a public CDN like google's to ensure the availabilty and caching.

[image]

Comment: so just to drag and drop a few elements your suggesting an overhead of 150kb...?

Comment: I find it highly unlikely you'd be using JUST droppable part of the library. Typically smoeone thats using droppable will end up using more than one of the UIs features.. If you're that worried about 150kb, throw it in the footer of the page and only load it on the page that NEEDS this feature. Or you can lump it with the minified v. of jquery to minimize http requests.

Comment: Why do you assume the default for everything is "using jQuery"?

Comment: @Shyju do you even realize you can just load the draggable and droppable only as a custom build in jQUery UI squuezing the side even low ?

Comment: So why load full 150k of jQueryUI altogether ?

Comment: @Abhishek : The minified version is 50KB. it includes all modules, he can always download a customized version which has only what he wants

Answer (score 4):

The drag'n'drop interface is implemented using JavaScript. The JS will probably send XML HTTP requests (AJAX) that will be processed server-side (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.).

As a rule of thumb: if it needs computing in the client's browser, it will use JavaScript. If it needs computing on the server, it will use your favourite server-side language.

Comment: +1 for the only one *not* suggesting to just throw `jQuery` at it.

Comment: Of course I'm not. I'm a jQuery fan, but I am aware that other JavaScript frameworks are AJAX-capable. For instance, Dojo might be as good a choice as jQuery. The framework choice is up to the OP. Additionally, he mentions Google. Google doesn't use jQuery, but rather a custom-tailored JS framework :).

Answer (score 2):

look into jQuery with ajax
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

then use ajax function with jquery onBlur or onUpdate..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to implement this on the *client* side, so neither asp.net nor php (= your question tags) will be particularly helpful here. On the client side, you can use jQuery, an example can be found here:

- [jQuery UI: Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

What technology you will use strongly depends on your knowledge and preferences.

**MooTools**
http://mootools.net/
Demo: http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Cart

**jQuery**
http://jqueryui.com/
Demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

What framework you choose is a matter of taste. I recommend to take a look at http://jqueryvsmootools.com/

Comment: the *technology* will be the same, it will be javascript. If he chooses to use a framework however thats when preference comes into play :P.

Comment: @Loktar: He asked about IDE/Technology and used tags "PHP" and "ASP.NET". That's why I wrote about technologies (ASP.NET, PHP).